# Maven integration-test failed: includes0 has null value

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-failsafe-plugin

My build recently started failing when trying to do `mvn clean install` I've not noticed previously because it builds and executes junit tests fine from eclipse. Any idea regarding the cause of the below error?

Maven log snippet:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.979s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jan 23 09:13:43 GMT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/220M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.11:integration-test (failsafe-integration-tests) on project ThinkFinance: Execution failsafe-integration-tests of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.11:integration-test failed: includes0 has null value -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.11:integration-test (failsafe-integration-tests) on project ThinkFinance: Execution failsafe-integration-tests of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.11:integration-test failed: includes0 has null value
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:225)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution failsafe-integration-tests of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.11:integration-test failed: includes0 has null value
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: includes0 has null value
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.PropertiesWrapper.addList(PropertiesWrapper.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.BooterSerializer.serialize(BooterSerializer.java:95)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:199)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAllProviders(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:176)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>My Company2</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <artifactId>MyCompany</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>MyCompany</name>
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>parallel</id>
            <properties>
                <include.tests>**/ParallelRunners/*Tests.java</include.tests>
                <junit.threadCount>15</junit.threadCount>
                <junit.parallel>classes</junit.parallel>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>allTestsSequential</id>
            <properties>
                <include.tests>
                    **/P0Regression.java
                </include.tests>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>smoke</id>
            <properties>
                <include.tests>
                    **/RunSmokeTests.java
                </include.tests>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>ThisTest</id>
            <properties>
                <include.tests>
                    **/RunThisTest.java
                </include.tests>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>All</id>
            <properties>
                <include.tests>
                    **/All.java
                </include.tests>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>clearWebserverCache</id>
            <properties>
                <include.tests>
                    **/clearWebserverCache.java
                </include.tests>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>My Company2</groupId>
            <artifactId>SeleniumFrameworkCore</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.29</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- these 2 are needed for communicating wih a REST API usin JSON Strings as the data interchange format. 
        It might eventually make sense to move this to a seperate core project -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>       
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.11</version>
                <configuration>
                    <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
                    <threadCount>${junit.threadCount}</threadCount>
                    <parallel>${junit.parallel}</parallel>
                    <includes>
                        <include>${include.tests}</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>

                    <execution>
                        <id>failsafe-integration-tests</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- DisABLED FAILSAFE VERIFY WHILE TESTING POSH REPORTER 
                    <execution>
                        <id>failsafe-verify</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    -->
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Disable unit tests -->
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>My Company2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>posh-cucumber-reporter-mojo</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>execution</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <projectName>My Company Smoke Tests </projectName>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-html-reports</outputDirectory>
                                <jsonLocation>${project.build.directory}/JSON/</jsonLocation>
                                <buildNumber>RC_2014_01_21_1 Revision: 27309 on QA 64</buildNumber>
                                <enableFlashCharts>true</enableFlashCharts>
                                <skippedFails>true</skippedFails>
                                <undefinedFails>true</undefinedFails>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                </configuration>
                <!-- Only generate project reports -->
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>failsafe-report-only</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>CheckStyle.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
                <configuration>
                  <groups>
                    <group>
                      <title>Test Step Documentation</title>
                      <!--
                      Include packages:
                        MyApp.StepDefinitions
                      and all subpackages
                      -->
                      <packages>MyApp.StepDefinitions*</packages>
                    </group>
                    <group>
                      <title>MyApp Documentation</title>
                      <packages>MyApp*</packages>
                    </group>
                  </groups>        
                </configuration>
              </plugin>         
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you show your pom file?

Comment: It looks like having no profile activated the property in the execution for maven-failsafe is empty...Just try to activate one of your profiles.

Comment: Thanks khmarbaise for the suggestion. It lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

What is the value for the `include.test` property? Could it be that it's not set properly, i.e. it will be `null` just like the error message says?

```
<includes>
    <include>${include.tests}</include>
</includes>
```

Try running `mvn -Dinclude.test=A` and see if the error message changes (shouldn' be a `NullpointerExcpetion`at least.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions everyone. I ran mvn clean and then a profile. That did the trick.

```
call mvn clean
call mvn -Psmoke verify -e -fae
```

Note: `mvn clean install` still gives build failure. I think this may be a seperate question: What is the purpose of `mvn install`, do I even need it?